# Default CNAME when DNS quering

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, cname-record

I have a domain, with a number of CNAME records to

www.mydomain.com
mail.mydomain.com
ftp.mydomain.com

Now, what I would like to achieve is that if any other subdomain is queried or the domain itself is queried, I would like to have www.mydomain.com returned such that if

mydomain.com or inexistent.mydomain.com are queried, www.mydomain.com is returned by default.

I am not sure how this is possible if it is? Any help is appreciated.

John

Answer (score 4):

for inexistent.mydomain.com just add

```
*.mydomain.com. CNAME www.mydomain.com.
```

But you can't CNAME mydomain.com as it's root of your zone. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655235/is-root-domain-cname-to-other-domain-allowed-by-dns-rfc

But you can create A record for mydomain.com, and have `*.mydomain.com. CNAME mydomain.com.`. In this case everything that ends with .mydomain.com would resolve to same ip.

Comment: Although, I'd recommend setting up the A record instead of the CNAME. e.g. `*.example.com IN A 127.0.0.1` It reduces the number of lookups made to the DNS server.

Comment: I am aware of that but I guess there's no other option since I am using a multi-site on a single IP setup using Apache VirtualHosts.

Comment: @John But what has a CNAME to do with Apache's VirtualHosts? Or better: Who told you that they only work with CNAMEs?

Comment: Can't get this done on godaddy... There's a limit of number of records in my zone file. But a wildcard record should count just as one no?

Comment: Yes, wildcard is just one record. And AFAIR godaddy limit is pretty high - never faced it with quite large zones.

Comment: I've read on the net that you can actually do a '**' instead of an '*'... Have tried that just now... Dont know if it really works yet.

Comment: A CNAME and an A record will work exactly the same with respect to virtual hosts. The client will still follow the DNS to decide what address to connect to and will still set the host header to the original host it was looking for.